# Ansible fails basic echo on remote node

Tags: ansible

I'm currently testing Ansible to see if it can make a viable backend for an updating system on our embedded enviroment. And I have a problem getting it to work fully.

I have two machines, that are connected via ethernet and can communicate with each other through ssh. Both have python 2.7, openssh as an ssh client and running an ssh server. Both have ssh-key authentication. I can, from the Control Machine, ssh into the other machine and invoke python there without any issues. Ansible works on the local machine, but has problems manipulating the rmeote machine at all.

Using this hosts file:

```
localhost              ansible_connection=local
192.168.100.212        ansible_connection=ssh ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

The call

```
ansible all -a "echo Hello World!"
```

Fails with the following message:

```
localhost | success | rc=0 >>
Hello World!

192.168.100.212 | FAILED => Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/media/ext-1/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible-1.8-py2.7.egg/ansible/runner/__init__.py", line 568, in _executor
exec_rc = self._executor_internal(host, new_stdin)
File "/media/ext-1/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible-1.8-py2.7.egg/ansible/runner/__init__.py", line 708, in _executor_internal
return self._executor_internal_inner(host, self.module_name, self.module_args, inject, port, complex_args=complex_args)
File "/media/ext-1/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible-1.8-py2.7.egg/ansible/runner/__init__.py", line 937, in _executor_internal_inner
result = handler.run(conn, tmp, module_name, module_args, inject, complex_args)
File "/media/ext-1/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible-1.8-py2.7.egg/ansible/runner/action_plugins/normal.py", line 57, in run
return self.runner._execute_module(conn, tmp, module_name, module_args, inject=inject, complex_args=complex_args)
File "/media/ext-1/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible-1.8-py2.7.egg/ansible/runner/__init__.py", line 463, in _execute_module
self._transfer_str(conn, tmp, module_name, module_data)
File "/media/ext-1/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible-1.8-py2.7.egg/ansible/runner/__init__.py", line 294, in _transfer_str
conn.put_file(afile, remote)
File "/media/ext-1/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible-1.8-py2.7.egg/ansible/runner/connection_plugins/ssh.py", line 395, in put_file
(p, stdin) = self._run(cmd, indata)
File "/media/ext-1/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible-1.8-py2.7.egg/ansible/runner/connection_plugins/ssh.py", line 107, in _run
stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
File "/media/ext-1/python/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/media/ext-1/python/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I am having trouble determining what is causing this issue. I have tested a more extensive playbook, and it has no trouble executing the whole thing on the localhost but fails with the same stascktrace on the remote machine.

Comment: in the future, use -vvvv to get more debugging/output.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to find that it was due to the lack of an sftp client, configuring it to work with scp did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work!

```
$ ssh-copy-id -i /home/(*UserName*)/.ssh/id_rsa.pub (*dest: hostname/IPADDR*)
```